# Como AutoAjustar Fuente de un label?

Tags: c#

Tengo un pequeño proyecto en C#, lo que quisiera hacer es que cuando el label salga  del GroupBox al que tengo asignado este reajuste su fuente para que no se salga del GroupBox

Lo intente con este code pero cuando se sale del GroupBox el texto se corta, y el punto es que salga todo completo...

```
private void lblTotal_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (lblTotal.Size.Width > gpoCotizador.Size.Width)
      {
          lblTotal.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", lblTotal.Font.Size - 1, FontStyle.Bold);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Método 1:**

Esto podría ser un poco ineficiente, pero funciona de esta manera brusca:

```
while(lblTotal.Width < System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(lblTotal.Text, 
      new Font(lblTotal.Font.FontFamily, lblTotal.Font.Size, lblTotal.Font.Style)).Width)
{
    lblTotal.Font = new Font(lblTotal.Font.FontFamily, lblTotal.Font.Size - 0.5f, lblTotal.Font.Style);
}
```

> Haciendo algunos bucles para calcular la fuente de la etiqueta en función del tamaño del texto.

---

**Método 2:**

Siguiendo tu propio ejemplo en vez de usar el evento `Resize`, deberías usar el evento `TextChanged`:

```
private void lblTotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lblTotal.Size.Width > gpoCotizador.Size.Width)
    {
        lblTotal.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", lblTotal.Font.Size - 1, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

Ya que en realidad **no estas ajustando el tamaño del `Label` redimencionadolo en tiempo de ejecución**, sino que lo que ha cambiado es el valor de la propiedad `Text`

Esto es asumiendo que tu `lblTotal` tome diferentes textos de mayor y menor caracteres.

> Ejemplo:
>
> `lblTotal.Text = "Esto es un texto corto";`
>
> `lblTotal.Text = "Esto es un texto mas largo que se sale del GroupBox";`

En la pregunta `if` puedes probar preguntar `lblTotal.Text.Length > ...` en ves de preguntar por el `Size.Width`

**NOTA: No aseguro que esto funcione correctamente, lo estoy haciendo sin probar en un compilador**

---

**Método 3:**

Como otra sugerencia, si esta no es una solución adecuada, además del `Size` de la fuente del label, podrías jugar con la propiedad `AutoSize`, `lblTotal.AutoSize = false;` para calcular un tamaño adecuado para este en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Me funciono la primera opcion, por mas que intentaba con el label no lograba hacerlo

Comment: @ChristianGtz Me alegra haber sido de ayuda